# csproj file is forcefully modified in error when any project is opened in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, wcf, iis-express

I recently modified the applicationhost.config file, turning windows authentication on for IISExpress.

```
<windowsAuthentication enabled="true">
                <providers>
                    <add value="Negotiate" />
                    <add value="NTLM" />
                </providers>
 </windowsAuthentication>
```

I think it might have been from this point on where - 
I open Visual Studio and load a project, and get the following -

"The following settings were applied to the project('ProjectName') based on settings for the local instance of IIS Express. If you need to change these settings, use the Properties window (F4).

Windows Authentication: enabled"

http://blogs.objectsharp.com/post/2013/05/08/IIS-Express-Default-Settings.aspx 
Check out this link for images of the message.

The big issue for me here is that it checks the file out under my name on TFS. If I right click on the project, source control, then undo changes - I will get the same message again and the project csproj is checked out under my name again.

How do I stop Visual Studio or IISExpress from trying to sync these settings everytime???

Thanks

Comment: You need to close VS, delete the applicationhost.config file from your local system, open VS again ( not the project/solution) and in TFS, get recurring latest version on that file.

Comment: @DinoMyte Thanks for that, it worked.